# Adonis query if condition

Tags: javascript, filter, pagination

My question is simple. Am on Adonis 5 ts, I have a filter function with paginate that work fine. But I need to paginate only when userType is Insurance. In the type is Admin then I don't need to paginate function.

```
    policies = await queryBuilder
      .where((query) => {
        if (productCategory) {
          query.where('targetType', productCategory)
        }
        if (dataForFilter.registerDateFrom) {
          query.where('createdAt', '>=', dataForFilter.registerDateFrom)
        }
        if (dataForFilter.registerDateTo) {
          query.where('createdAt', '<=', dataForFilter.registerDateTo)
        }
      // and so on...
      })
      .preload('package', (query) => {
        query.preload('product', (query) => {
          query.preload('productCategory')
          query.preload('company')
        })
      })
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .if(dataForFilter.userTypeResultData.userType === 'Insurance', (query) => {
        query.paginate(page, limit)
      })
```

I searched and I found that in Adonis 5 I can do .if on the query. but the problem is that this query in if is the new query. I need there results of the search query. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you must use "andWhere" method from adonisjs, not "where" method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).